# Android : How to remove org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56 - from dependency graph and use org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.65

Tags: android, build, dependencies

How to remove org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:**1.56** - from dependency graph

and use org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:**1.65**

gradle version is: gradle-7.7.1-bin.zip

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'

JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_242"

Command : gradlew app:dependencies

```
 |    +--- org.bouncycastle:b**cpkix-jdk15on:1.56**
 |    |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
 |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
```

Comment: Does your project directly include org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56 or is it required by some other library that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to specify the version in your build.gradle. Maybe it is already there and you just have to change the version number. Or maybe it is a dependency of a depdency. In that case you can override the version by specifying the bouncycastle library at the desired version. For example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.65'
}
```

[This gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_version_alignment.html) elaborates on how resolution happens.

Comment: ```1. org.bouncycastle:bcpkix library used by android lint. 
2. implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.65' not removing old version of  jdk15on:1.56```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [dependencySubstitution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions.html). Something like this works for me (in build.gradle)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        bouncyCastleVersion = '1.76'
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module('org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on') using module("org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:${bouncyCastleVersion}")
            substitute module('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on') using module("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:${bouncyCastleVersion}")
            substitute module('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk15on') using module("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk18on:${bouncyCastleVersion}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a related regression starting in Gradle 8.3:  https://discuss.gradle.org/t/dependencysubstitutions-regression-in-8-3/47250